# WordPress, Get Value from Meta Data object

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a custom cropper, and I'm getting the data using the following:

```
$imageSingle = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(),'image',true);
```

It's returning the following when I print it out 'print_r':

```
{"original_image":"61","cropped_image":"61"}
```

I've tried the following but can't return the ID of the cropped image itself:

```
<?php echo $imageSingle[0]->cropped_image;?>
<?php echo $imageSingle[0]['cropped_image'];?>
```

Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try `$imageSingle->cropped_image` or `$imageSingle['cropped_image']`

Comment: @PrasunJajodia i tried both of those options.  The First didn't return anything, the second returned a singular bracket '{'

Comment: use foreach loop for $imageSingle variable then you get key and value

Comment: @RMH I think the data is JSON encoded then.. just do `$imageSingle = json_decode($imageSingle)` and then `$imageSingle['cropped_image']`

Comment: @PrasunJajodia, that json_decode, when print_r against the variable returns: stdClass Object ( [original_image] => 61 [cropped_image] => 61 )

Comment: exactly.. now you've got a php object from which you can retrieve values ;)

Comment: @PrasunJajodia ah, sorry, i meant to say that echoing this out: '$imageSingle['cropped_image']' crashed the page

Comment: It's an object not an array..
do `$imageSingle->cropped_image` and everything will work out

Comment: adding it as an answer just in case someone else comes snooping around with the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is JSON encoded..
so after

`$imageSingle = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(),'image',true);`

you do

`$imageSingle = json_decode($imageSingle);`

Now.. The value is in `$imageSingle->cropped_image`

Comment: YYYAAASS.  Thank you!  I also never considered it could have been json encoded.  Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

`get_post_meta()` return a object, not an array, you should be remove `[0]`, like this:

`<?php echo $imageSingle->cropped_image; ?>`